# Form not pre-populated Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular8

I have an API service which returns an array of objects. Each object has two fields name and usage. I am creating a form dynamically where the number of form fields equals the number of objects inside array. Name of the form field is the `name` and it should be prepopulated with `usage` value. I am able to create the form and name the form fields but the `usage` value is not displaying let along correct value in each form field.
My TS file code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.apiCall.getArray()
    .subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        this.receivedData = res;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.receivedData.length; i ++){
          this.currentName  = this.receivedData[i].name;
          this.currentUsage = this.receivedData[i].usage;
          this.name.push(this.currentName);
          this.usage.push(this.currentUsage);
        }
```

name and usage are arrays where values are stored. In my HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group *ngFor="let plans of name">
        <label>{{plans}}</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="usage" name="usage" value="usage" [(ngModel)]="usage">
      </div>
      </div>
      </form>
```

Now my form fields show correct field names but the fields are empty. They should be pre-filled with respective usage value and the user should be able to change the values as per they wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are some problems with your code.

First, if you want to assign a value to an attribute within an Angular `*ngFor` loop, you need to do something like `item.foo`. Next to that, square brackets `[]` are needed to actually pass the value into the attribute and loop through the array of data, because the data is dynamic.

Last problem is that you can't assign numbers (I assumed `item.usage` would be a `number`) to strings like `id` and `name`. It's also because you have added the `type="number"` to the `input` field.

This will result in the following setup in HTML. I am looping through the data with `let item of items` and picking the keys where I need them.

```html
<form>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let item of items">
        <label>{{item.name}}</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" [id]="item.name" [name]="item.name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.usage">
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

With some mock data it turns out to work.

```js
  received = [
  {
    name: 'Field 1',
    usage: 123456,
  },
  {
    name: 'Field 2',
    usage: 4655454,
  },
  {
    name: 'Field 3',
    usage: 54445,
  }];
```

See [this StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eaxt5p?file=src/app/app.component.html) for a working example, fixing all of the problems I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Roy, if you use [(ngModel)] you need NOT use [value]

Comment: @Eliseo Ah, yes. Forgot about that, changed it.

Comment: @Roy It has worked wonderfully. Now the form is created and is pre-populated with usage values. If user changes some usage value and hit submit. How do I create a json object to send to the backend as the ngModel value is dynamic, how can I create that? I have tried ```onSubmit{
                                                 this.changedValues = this.item.usage;}```
But suppose there are 4 form fields how do I create separate parameter to add in json and also suppose i add another parameter in item which is ```id``` how can I send that along with changed usage value. Thank you for any help

Comment: @Vishavgeet I see you asked another question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771703/create-json-object-from-dynamic-ngmodel

Comment: Hi @Roy Yes I am actually new to the stackoverflow and the next half for this question asked in comments did not gain any views. So I simply asked it. I am new to Angular as well and was not sure how the updated json would be sent. But these both answers combined were exactly what I was looking into. Thanks once agian.