# Create JSON object from Dynamic NgModel

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, angular8

I have a service which returns a JSON of type `array[obj1{name, usage, id}, obj2{name, usage, id}]` on HTML page I am creating a form with form field = name and it is pre-populated with value = usage. Ex: if there are 2 objects inside array where name1=a usage1=1 and name2=b and usage2=2, 2 form fields will be created.  Form field names will be name1 and name2 and will be filled already with usage1 and usage2 value respectively. I am doing this with this code:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let item of items">
        <label>{{item.name}}</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" [id]="item.name" [name]="item.name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.usage">
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

It is working fine. Now suppose user changes the value for usage1 and usage2. On submit button I have to create a json object in typescript and send it in the API. I am facing issues to create the JSON object. I have tried:

```
onSubmit{
        this.changedValues = this.items.usage;
console.log(this.changedValues);
}
```

But console.log return undefined. Json object I am expecting should be something of they type:

```
changedValues[{upadatedUsage1, id1},{updatedUsage2, id2}]
```

How can I create a json object dynamically and also how can I send the correct id with the correct updated usage value. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for undefined value is that, *items* is an array and hence doesn't have the property *usage*

```js
onSubmit {
    this.changedValues = this.items;
    console.log(this.changedValues);
}
```

This should give the array with updated values.

Comment: It is perfect @Chandra. Thank you a lot